# compare some functions

Tags: expression-test

Assume that I have three function:

```
sum1[n_] := Sum[Cos[k/n], {k, 0, n}]
sum2[n_] := Sum[Sin[k/n], {k, 0, 2n}]
sum3[n_] := Sum[Cos[k + 1/2n], {k, 0, 2n - 1}]
```

For each $n<100$, how can I compare these three function?

For example Mathematica tells me sum2[3]> sum1[3]>sum3[3] or sum3[5]>sum[5]>sum1[5].

Comment: How about plotting them as a function of n?

Comment: `And @@ Table[sum2[n] > sum1[n] > sum3[n], {n, 1, 100}]` evaluates to `True`

Answer (score 1):

`DiscretePlot[{sum1[n], sum2[n], sum3[n]}, {n, 1, 100}]`[image]

Comment: Better still, plot the differences

Comment: Plot doesn't work good for large domains. Isn't there any way else?or only way is that I must use several If?